# open Rstudio with certain scripts in Rproj

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm creating exercises for a course I'm teaching.
Currently, my plan is for each weekly exercise to have it's own .Rproj file.
Can I include the Rstudio source documents (opened scripts) somehow?

I have, say, 3 Rscripts (templates) for a given exercise that I would like students to see automatically when opening the .Rproj file.

From my projects, it seems these are stored in `.Rproj.user/5A57A303/sources/per/t` (when Rstudio is closed) with 8 digit IDs like 596DDB3F. It seems like a bad idea to create these files manually...
Any better ideas?

Comment: Honestly I'm just not a big fan of the idea here.  Why not just include a README or some other sort of documentation outlining what is in the files and which ones they'll need?  If a student wants to use an editor other than Rstudio are you going to allow them to do that?

Comment: There is a readme and students can use whatever editor they like.
Since many will use Rstudio, I want to provide a convenience function that generates the task _and opens it_

Answer (score 0):

I did end up creating the files manually.
It needs the following content:

```
"id": "596DDB3F",
"path": "full/path.R",
"type": "r_source",
"project_path": "path.R"
```

There must also be a corresponding file `596DDB3F-contents`.
I developed code that automates the whole process in [codeoceanR](https://github.com/openHPI/codeoceanR/blob/main/R/rt_file2openedlist.R) and it works like a charm.
Overkill, sure, but it was fun tryig things out :).